# Setting up a pentest lab with windows xp and kali as guest on virtualbox only one way connections?

Tags: windows, networking, virtual-machine, ping, kali-linux

I have Kali linux 2016 and Windows XP installed as guest in VirtualBox.  I followed an instructions on superuser for making the two guest talk to each other.

Now Windows XP is capable of pinging kali but when I try to ping Windows XP it says n packets sent 0 packets recived all packets lost.

This is the link for the instruction(I did the edit part)

[Can't ping between two guest OS in Virtualbox](https://superuser.com/questions/710451/cant-ping-between-two-guest-os-in-virtualbox)

Answer (score 0):

turn off firewall in windows xp ... then you can ping xp from kali ..

Comment: how does this answer the question?